# How to get the XId of a Gtk::Window in Gtkmm4

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, gtkmm, gtkmm4

I am using Gtkmm4, and lots of API has been removed. In Gtk3 one could use `Gtk::Window::get_xid` (inherited from `Gdk::Window`), but thats not possible anymore, because `Gdk::Window` has been renamed to `Gdk::Surface`, and `Gtk::Window` seems to not inherit from it anymore. But, one can always get the XId of a `Gdk::Surface` using `GDK_SURFACE_XID(surface)`. How can i get the `Gdk::Surface` of a `Gtk::Window`, or alternatively, get the XId from a `Gtk::Window` directly ?
Note : i need only solutions using Gtkmm 4, not Gtkmm 3 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that deals with the underlying surfaces got split off into a separate interface, [`Gtk::Native`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Native.html), which `Gtk::Window` then implements. `Gtk::Native` has a method [`get_surface()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Native.html#a646b2a7230a58cadf1570a26bf656dfd) which should just work like `Gtk::Window::get_window()` did in GTK 3.